# Implementation of ZoomtoSpan Android

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

Is there any way to implement zoomToSpan functionality in custom Maps in Android which is not Google Map. ?

Say I have a class M which extends surfaceView (I'm loading my custom map on the surfaceview), I have no functionality in my program to handle automatically set the zoomlevel accordingly when there are more than 10 markers. I want to set my zoomlevel accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i found one basic example of 
Zoom and span on a cluster of points
http://www.anddev.org/zoom_and_span_on_a_cluster_of_points-t464.html

If u want to handle zoom controller , you should take one Timer which will check every 5 second your zoom level (Its works smiler like zoom control listener ).

Good Luck !!

Comment: MAP Is the big thing bro ,, 
in which lot of image has rastring at second of time ,

Comment: That's not what am looking for. I am not using google map, I have created my own map and I want to implement the functionality like zoomToSpan and mapController etc in my App.

Comment: what u need in map controller ?